Variance of ARMA$\left(2,2\right)$ model

Find $Var(∇Y_t)$ if $Y_t = 5 + 2Y_{t-1} - 1.7Y_{t-2} + 0.7Y_{t-3} + e_t - 0.5e_{t-1} + 0.25e_{t-2}$.

I've reduced this down to $∇Y_t = 5 + ∇Y_{t-1} - 0.7∇Y_{t-2} + e_t - 0.5e_{t-1} + 0.25e_{t-2}$. Now, assuming $W_t = ∇Y_t - \mu$, where $\mu$ is some constant, we're able to reform this into an ARMA$\left(2,2\right)$ model: $$W_t = W_{t-1} - 0.7W_{t-2} + e_t - 0.5e_{t-1} + 0.25e_{t-2}$$
Breaking down the model into AR/MA characteristic polynomial form:
$(1 - B_1 + 0.7B_1^2)W_t = (1 - 0.5B_2 + 0.25B_2^2)e_t$, we find all roots $|B_1|>1$ and $|B_2|>1$, so the stationary and invertible requirements are met. Therefore, $E(W_t) = 0$, hence $Var(∇Y_t) = Var(W_t) = E(W_t^2) = E\left(W_t(W_{t-1} - 0.7W_{t-2} + e_t - 0.5e_{t-1} + 0.25e_{t-2}) \right)$. I'm unable to simplify this down further.

Usually the easiest way to do such calculations is to exploit the bilinearity of covariance.
